# Issue Accessing SVN Repository with Both SVN and HTTP Protocols

Tags: svn

I'm trying to access a SVN repository that I created (using svnadmin) on my local machine using the HTTP protocol, but I can't determine the URL.  Is there additional configuration I need to supply to access it as HTTP?  I have no issues accessing it using SVN protocol.  I just want to do some performance tuning and compare the protocols.  Any ideas?  Commands used to create repo are below.

**Repository Creation and Server Start Commands:**

```
$cd
$svnadmin create my-repository
$svnserve -d -r /Users/myusername
```

**SVN:**

```
$ svn info svn://localhost/my-repository
Path: my-repository
URL: svn://localhost/my-repository
Relative URL: ^/
Repository Root: svn://localhost/my-repository
Repository UUID: 2de7b13c-0139-45f6-a121-4d8cc6918849
Revision: 86
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Rev: 86
Last Changed Date: 2013-12-04 11:58:03 -0800 (Wed, 04 Dec 2013)
```

**HTTP:**

```
$ svn info http://localhost/my-repository
svn: E120108: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://localhost/my-repository'
svn: E120108: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

Comment: Did you set up your web server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [setup Apache httpd with mod_dav_svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html).

In general svnserve will be faster than httpd.  httpd is more popular because originally svnserve didn't support encryption except through ssh tunnels (it does now via SASL) and it didn't support nearly as many authentication methods (again SASL support changed this).

The only major feature that httpd has that svnserve doesn't is the ability to browse the repositories with a web browser directly (Note that this isn't the same as say browsing with viewvc).

One benefit of httpd is that since it uses HTTP it generally goes through firewalls without special configuration.  It can also be proxied (allowing for a caching proxy to help speed it up).

Comment: Ben Reser @ I have svnserve installed with apr,apr-util, serf. The apxs was not used during the install. [--with-apxs[=FILE] Build shared Apache modules]. i see http 404 errror. Do i need to install svn with -apxs for http to work through svnserve.

Comment: svnserve is a different protocol and is not served via HTTP or Apache.  The apxs setting is only used for configuring Apache.  If you want a svnserve build you don't need to do anything with apxs.

Comment: Ben @ Assume to provide http READ only access to svn repositories via Apache, I do not need SVN installed. Is this right. Generally, to configure http access via apache, Apache will be installed with prerequisites modules that svn and apache needs like Apr, Apr-util, SSL, ldap, authz etc. Then svn will be installed with Apr modules available/reference in Apache. In my case, I have already having svn installed and svnserve running which is not installed with Apache.

Comment: You don't need the command line installed since Apache just uses the library.  But you do need the libraries.  It's difficult to talk in specifics since different systems break up their packages in different ways.  So sure if your system has packages for just the libraries you can avoid having the command line installed.

Comment: Ben @ I am in a situation where I have Apache instance installed in Redhat without SVN modules namely mod_dav_svn and mod_authz_svn for http access. I googled and found that compiling mod_dav_svn and other svn modules and copy to apache /modules directory would make the apache serve http for svn repository. I used --with-apxs in Subversion 1.9.2 source and apxs version as 2.2.17. But it said that i need use the higher apxs version. Now I am trying to compile apache. Is this right, am i going in the right direction.

Comment: Sounds like it yes.  The instructions in the INSTALL file for Subversion will be helpful.